# Approximation of the convolution operator

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, convolution

I am trying to convolve two functions:

$f(t) = e^{-h t}$

$g(t) = e^{-(e^{-t})^2}$

$(f*g)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(t-\tau)g(\tau) d\tau = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-h(t-\tau)} e^{-(e^{-\tau})^2} d\tau$

Unfortunately, neither Mathematica nor Maple mastered this integral.

Are there any ways to approximate the convolution operator and get at least an approximate solution?

I would be grateful for any advice and help.

Comment: You can get a series for this that works for all values of $t$, or an approximation that works for small $t$, after the substitution $x = e^{-\tau}$. You cannot just ask for an approximation without saying anything about assumptions that can or can't be made about your constants such as $t$ and $h$.

Comment: I need to work with all t, both small and large.I need to work with all t, both small and large. As for h, this is the range [1; inf]

Comment: Is this a good variant?.[Convolution, as sum](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Convolution/images/SumApprox.gif)

Comment: $g(t)$ is quite close to $1$ for all but the smallest positive $t$, so a start would be to replace it by $1+(g(t)-1)$ and use pointwise estimates for $g(t)-1$ to bound the contribution of the second part.

Comment: That's not so good. Because i need to work with a wide class of functions. Are there more advanced ways?