# Convolution using Integral Transforms

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform, convolution, integral-transforms

Returning to the question:

[Approximation of the convolution operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743374/approximation-of-the-convolution-operator?noredirect=1#comment7697800_3743374)

And new discussion:

[Convolution using the Laplace integral transform of certain functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225239/convolution-using-the-laplace-integral-transform-of-certain-functions?noredirect=1#comment573367_225239)

$f(t) = e^{-t}$

$g(t) = e^{-(e^{-t})^2}$

Using the convolution property, we can transform it into a product of folding functions, each of which is obtained using the direct Laplace transform of each of the original functions, i.e.:

$(f*g)(t) \rightarrow L^{-1}(L(f(t)) \cdot L(g(t)))$

But it is known that the original functions must meet certain requirements.

With these functions, the Laplace transform will look like:

$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2},1\right)}{2 s+2}$

The inverse Laplace transform from this function is not searched. Mathematica and Maple do not produce adequate results.

How to use this approach to work with a wider class of functions? Use more advanced integral transforms? If so, which ones?

I will be glad to any advice and help.

Comment: Better to link the discussion in mathematica.SE too: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225239/1871

Comment: The problem is solved by expanding in a Taylor series the function exp (φ) for φ.