# Is it possible to find a solution to this equation, reducing it to the Fredholm equation?

Tags: integral-equations

To continue the questions:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743374/approximation-of-the-convolution-operator?noredirect=1#comment7697800_3743374

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744687/convolution-using-integral-transforms?noredirect=1#comment7702418_3744687

[Convolution using the Laplace integral transform of certain functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225239/convolution-using-the-laplace-integral-transform-of-certain-functions?noredirect=1#comment573367_225239)

[Approximate solution of a nonlinear ODE in the form of a Fourier series containing the coefficients of the initial ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224544/approximate-solution-of-a-nonlinear-ode-in-the-form-of-a-fourier-series-containi/224672?noredirect=1#comment572998_224672)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745783/find-an-approximate-formula-of-one-of-the-components-of-the-solution-of-the-diff

I have a differential equation, for example:

$\frac{dx}{dt}= \mu \cdot e^{-x^2} \cdot a_1 \cdot \sin(\omega_1 \cdot t) + a_1 \cdot \cos(\omega_1 \cdot t)$

```
{\[Alpha] = 0.1, \[Omega] = 2 Pi 0.1, \[Mu] = 5
```

His numerical solution is as follows:

[image]

The figure shows that one of the components of the solution can be:

$x(t) ≈ e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t}$

[image]

If we represent the solution of the equation in the form:

$x(t) = e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t} + \Delta(t)$

And substitute in the original equation, we get:

$\frac{e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t} + \Delta(t)}{dt}= \mu \cdot e^{-(e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t} + \Delta(t))^2} \cdot a_1 \cdot \sin(\omega_1 \cdot t) + a_1 \cdot \cos(\omega_1 \cdot t)$

Is it possible to somehow analytically and very approximately get a solution for $\Delta(t)$

**EDIT:**

I thought about this for a long time and came to the following assumption.

If we take the integral from both sides and transfer the $-  e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t}$ to the right side, then we can get the following equation:

$\Delta(t) - $$\int_{}^{} \mu \cdot e^{-(e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t} + \Delta(t))^2} \cdot a_1 \cdot \sin(\omega_1 \cdot t) + a_1 \cdot \cos(\omega_1 \cdot t) dt = -  e^{-\mu \cdot \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \cdot t}$

***But is it possible to solve this equation, like the Fredholm equation, and find $\Delta(t)$?***

I will be glad to be advised and helped.

Comment: This is Volterra equation. It can be solve numerically.

Comment: Take your time to close the question. Numerically solved, I agree. An approximate analytical solution is needed.

Comment: It is better to use differential equation for approximate solution. Are any restrictions for parameters $\mu , a_1, \omega_1 $?

Comment: There are only one restrictions on the parameters - they must be greater than zero. However, the system may become unstable. At what values is unknown. For simplicity, let's limit ourselves to a range of parameters like this: $\mu = [0,10]$,$\alpha_1 = [0,3]$,$\omega_1 = [0,5]$